# css style using url not found when site is accessed by its complete address

Tags: html, css, svg

I have some svg definitions on my file index.php located at localhost:8888/profile/index.php. The code  is called to use a svg symbol. On my css I styled the parent div of this svg using fill:url(/profile/#l4pButtonPin). When I access my web site by: 
"localhost:8888/profile/" or "localhost:8888/profile", the fill property works correctly filling the svg. However when I access my web site by:"localhost:8888/profile/index.php" the fill property does not work. It seems it can't find the url anymore. Would anyone know how to solve this issue or explain why does it happen ? ( Code fragments follow bellow )

---

fragment at index.php

```
<!-- SVG Defs and Symbols -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0"         height="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden">

    <!-- SVG Defs -->
    <defs>

        <!-- Linear gradient Looking for project button -->
        <lineargradient id="l4pButtonPin" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c7d1d6"/>
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#c8d1d6"/>
            <stop offset="0.22" stop-color="#e0e5e8"/>
            <stop offset="0.46" stop-color="#f1f4f5"/>
            <stop offset="0.7" stop-color="#fcfcfd"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
        </lineargradient>
    </defs>

    <!-- Looking for project button -->
    <symbol id="l4pButton" width="38" height="38">
        <rect x="ß8" y="1" rx="12" ry="12" width="22" height="36" />
        <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="11" />
        <!--circle cx="19" cy="26" r="11" /-->
    </symbol>
</svg>

<div>
    <div id="l4p" class="l4p">          
        <svg width="38" height="38">
            <use xlink:href="#l4pButton"/>
        </svg>
        <p>Active</p>
    </div>
</div>`
```

---

fragment at style.css

```
#l4pButton circle { fill: url(/profile/#l4pButtonPin); }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you load the stylesheet, and you haven't shared that

Comment: I have this piece of code on my index.php file ( located at http://localhost:8888/profile/index.php ): <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile/style.css" type="text/css">. My css file is located at http://localhost:8888/css/profile

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a matter of quotes:

```
fill: url("/profile/#l4pButtonPin");
```

Comment: Still does not work. I am avoiding using svg linear gradients on css now. As workaround I will use it only on the same file it was created (.html or .php)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is kinda old, but it's because of the lowercase letters in the linear gradient tag. It should be `linearGradient`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).